# batch job schedule issue

Tags: c#

**Question:**

there are 1000 images which has been divided into 100 pieces already. Each piece has 10 images.

I want to render each piece in a image listview and take a snapshot. For example:

After all the 10 images in piece1 rendered in the listview , take a snapshot, save the snapshot as piece001.png

repeat the same process for piece2, piece3, ...

**My solution:**

Currently, I am using loop and sleep to do the batch job:

I assume that each job will take 2 seconds, start the process which render the image into listview and take snapshot, then sleep 2 seconds waiting the process to finish

**problem:**

the solution above does't work well all the time. Sometimes the snapshot is blank image, which seems that the rendering is not finished yet. To enlarge the timer interval seems is not a good idea.

I am wondering what is the correct way to do it.

sample code

```
//customer event
public event EventHandler DatagridImageUpdated;

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    DatagridImageUpdated += SaveDataGridToPic; //if grid image updated, then capture and save

    Task task1  = ... //prepare images, saved to  Queue<Photo> photos_

    Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith(  //task2 load image to listview and capture photo
            task_finsihed =>
            {
                while (photos_.Count > 0)
                {
                    UpdateGridViewInvoke(); //process 10 images each round
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);  //wait 2 seconds
                }
            }
    );
}

private void UpdateGridViewInvoke()
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            UpdateGridView();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateGridView();
    }
}

    private void UpdateGridView()  //update grid with 10 images
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i)
        {
            Photo photo = photos_.Dequeue();
            for row, col ...
                dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value = getImage(photo.Name);
        }

        OnDatagridImageUpdated(EventArgs.Empty); //raise event
    }

//customer event --- update datagrid
//use this function to raise event
protected virtual void OnDatagridImageUpdated(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler handler = DatagridImageUpdated;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, e);
}


private void SaveDataGridToPic(object sndr, EventArgs ea)
{
    if (this.panel1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.panel1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {
          //capture grid and save image to disk
        } 
    }
    else
        //capture grid and save image to disk
}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of http://xyproblem.info ?

Comment: @MikeNakis Thanks Mike. I am a newbie to c#. I don't know where is the problem and what's the correct solution :( I will update the question to make it more clear

Comment: probaly there is a event to know when rendering is done. And then take the snapshot

Comment: @lordkain Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I will check it.